# R lattice levelplot, changing the background color and custom colorscale labels

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I have a lattice plot, I am trying to change its background but can't seem to make it work. I am also trying to add Custom heatmap labels (ranging from 1 to 5, and would like to add some text. )

```
par(bg = "yellow")
levelplot(as.matrix(x = c(1:5),y = c(5:1))
)
```

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The background should be settable in trellis.par.set()

Comment: I am not able to make it work, can you demonstrate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `ggplot`, `lattice` is based on grid graphics, not base R graphics, so setting the `par` won't have any effect. You can change the lattice pars, or alternatively you can do it after the fact using `grid.edit`:

```r
library(lattice)
library(grid)

levelplot(as.matrix(x = c(1:5), y = c(5:1)))
grid.edit("plot_01.background", gp = gpar(fill = "yellow"))
```

[image]

Needless to say, if you are looking for multiple formatting changes, easy annotations, custom scales and rich documentation, you should switch to ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5), aes(x, 0.5, fill = x)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = x), size = 10) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 5.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#ff77ff", mid = "white", high = "cyan",
                       midpoint = 3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFF80"),
        plot.margin = margin(150, 50, 150, 50),
        legend.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(lattice)
trellis.par.set(background = list(col="yellow"))
levelplot(as.matrix(x = c(1:5),y = c(5:1)), 
          scales=list(x=list(at=1:5, labels=LETTERS[1:5])))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response! It works, the labels I am trying to change is the color scale labels, when I applied the code it changed the x axis. Thank you for your time

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641186/r-levelplot-colorkey-label-and-color-range) for how to change the color key tick marks and labels.